# Is it possible to reuse constant names in different file scopes?

Tags: go

Is it possible to have two constants with the same name in different files?

foo.go

```
const {
    deviceId = 1     // I dont need this outside the file scope
}

type DeviceA struct {
    .. some fields.. 
    // I cannot make constant fields here
}

.. some methods ...
```

bar.go

```
const {
    deviceId = 2      // I dont need this outside the file scope
}

type DeviceB struct {
    .. some fields ..
    // I cannot make constant fields here
}

.. some methods ...
```

If I do this, I get that `deviceId` has been redeclared. How can I keep these constants in the scope of the file?

I would not mind using some kind of namespace for the constants if that were a solution to this.

Comment: There's no such thing as file scope in Go, and namespacing is done with packages. Since redeclaring a constant doesn't really make any sense, what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @JimB: Each file has a [implicit] file block containing all Go source text in that file.The scope of a declared identifier is the extent of source text in which the identifier denotes the specified constant, type, variable, function, label, or package.  https://golang.org/ref/spec

Comment: I have two implementations: struct+methods one in each file. Each one of these, has a constant device_id. This is different for each struct but still I consider it a constant. I would need to scope it some how, but keeping the same name

Comment: @peterSO: I could see how that might be confusing, but if that "file block" specification was the source of the confusion it should be mentioned in the question. Except for import statements, for all intents and purposes package level declarations aren't related to individual files.

Comment: I hope the update provides a bit more context

Comment: Why votes for closing?? I think it is a valid question! Sometimes stackoverflow is frustrating

Comment: This is not a sensible question. You cannot do that. Dead simple. There is no way to do this as it is forbidden by the language. So the question "How to do this?" is not a good SO question.

Comment: Thanks! A 'you cannot do that in golang' is enough and useful. I think it will help people that are looking to do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Packages](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Packages)
>
> Go programs are constructed by linking together packages. A package in
>   turn is constructed from one or more source files that together
>   declare constants, types, variables and functions belonging to the
>   package and which are accessible in all files of the same package.
>   Those elements may be exported and used in another package.
>
> [Source file organization](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Source_file_organization)
>
> Each source file consists of a package clause defining the package to
>   which it belongs, followed by a possibly empty set of import
>   declarations that declare packages whose contents it wishes to use,
>   followed by a possibly empty set of declarations of functions, types,
>   variables, and constants.

---

> [constants] belonging to the package are accessible in all files of the same package.

The fundamental Go compilation unit is the package. The source files in the package are merged to form the input to the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question: It is not possible to have two constants with the same name, in the same scope, the same package in separated files.

There is no namespace or file scope in Go.

However, it is possible to have two constants of the same name in the same package but declared at different scope:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

const a = 1

func main() {
    const a = 2
    fmt.Println(a) // output is 2
}
```

For details of scope, please see: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope